# Transmit QMap by QMimeData

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt5, qstring, qmap

Is any ideas how i can transmit `QMap<QString, QString>` in Drag and Drop mode by using `QMimeData`?

Now i convert `QMap` into `QString` like this:
`"key1:value1;key2:value2;...keyN:valueN"` and assigned it to `QMimeData::setText()`.

Then on `dropEvent()` i rebuild `QMap` from `QString`. Is this right way?

**Convert QString to QMap**

```
    ...
    QStringList splittedParams = params.split(";");
    QMap<QString, QString> *map = new QMap<QString, QString>();
    foreach(QString param, splittedParams)
    {
        if(param.isEmpty()) continue;
        QStringList str = param.split(":");
        map->insert(str[0], str[1]);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

That's going to fall apart if your strings contain the separators. For a more robust approach use something like

```
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
map >> ds;

mimeData->setData(QStringLiteral("your/mime/type"), ba);
```